# Find MAX() in database and plus 1

Tags: c#, mysql

```
        int hid = 0;
        int hid_auto = 0;
        //Đổ dữ liệu
        //HID
        if (conn_class.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand hid_sql = new MySqlCommand("SELECT MAX(hid) FROM hotel", conn_class.connection);
            hid = Convert.ToInt16(hid_sql.ExecuteScalar());
            hid_auto = hid + 1;

            conn_class.CloseConnection();
        }
        txt_Hid.Text = hid_auto.ToString();
//code that insert new record into database successfully
```

.......
Update: insert statement

```
if (general.TestEmail.IsEmail(txt_Email.Text) == true)
            {
                //Insert dữ liệu vào database
                email = txt_Email.Text;
                MySqlCommand them_hotel = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO quan_li.hotel (hid, name, star, address, province, phone, fax, email) VALUES (@hid, @name, @star, @address, @province, @phone, @fax, @email)");
                them_hotel.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                them_hotel.Connection = conn_class.connection;
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hid", txt_Hid.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_Ten.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@star", txt_Sao.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txt_DiaChi.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@province", txt_Tinh.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txt_DienThoai.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", txt_Fax.Text);
                them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txt_Email.Text);

                conn_class.OpenConnection();
                them_hotel.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn_class.CloseConnection();
                thanh_cong = "Đã thêm khách sạn thành công";
            }
```

I want to find MAX() value of column hid then plus 1 and send to textbox. This event is in a button but the second time I press that button, the value always shows as the first time the button is pressed.

Ex:
1st: MAX() = 9 -> +1 -> 10 in textbox. -> 10 is inserted into database
2nd ...n: 10 in textbox and 10 is inserted into database (2 rows with same value).

How to +1 from MAX() value from the database?

Thank you for you help.

P/s: sorry for my bad english.

Comment: is this all one method? your insert isn't present in the code you posted, so is it inserting into the hotel table? is `hid` an autoincrementing ID?

Comment: Your inserting logic must be faulty. Is hid correct in the insert statement ? Why not make an identity out of it and not bother with a max value in the first place ?

Comment: are you sure that on second time `conn_class.OpenConnection()` is _true_?

Comment: @Kritner Yes, one method. The insert code is quite long but it works correctly because new record is added to the database. The only problem is the value of hid column. hid is an autoincrementing ID. I'm a begginer, I dont know how to work on autoincrementing ID, so I think about this....

Comment: @DannyHai an `identity` column (for sql server, might have different terminology for other databases) is an auto incrementing number.  If there's no records in your table, you insert one, first record then has an ID of 1 without specifying the value of the column, second record gets 2, and so on.  Note there are caveats to the previous statement, but that is the basic idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read everything you wrote, including in the comments.

You look like you have a form, which has a field related to hid field in your table. You are trying to show the value of the next ID (hid) to the person who is using the form.

Well, you can show the value of the ID (hid), but knowing that your table has a hid with autoincrement then you do not need to include the field hid at the time of insertion.

Should look like:

```
if (general.TestEmail.IsEmail(txt_Email.Text) == true)
{
    //Insert dữ liệu vào database
    email = txt_Email.Text;
    MySqlCommand them_hotel = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO quan_li.hotel (name, star, address, province, phone, fax, email) VALUES (@name, @star, @address, @province, @phone, @fax, @email)");
    them_hotel.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    them_hotel.Connection = conn_class.connection;
    //them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hid", txt_Hid.Text);
    them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_Ten.Text);
    them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@star", txt_Sao.Text);
    them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txt_DiaChi.Text);
    them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@province", txt_Tinh.Text);
    them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txt_DienThoai.Text);
    them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", txt_Fax.Text);
    them_hotel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txt_Email.Text);

    conn_class.OpenConnection();
    them_hotel.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn_class.CloseConnection();
    thanh_cong = "Đã thêm khách sạn thành công";
}
```

Comment: I can not voteup because I dont have enough rep. I'm beginner and I didn't know about AUTO INCREMENT. Thank you for letting me know. Everything works fine. :)

Comment: But you can vote this like right answer. You are welcome. As I saw, you already had the autoincrement collumn, you didn't need to change nothing at your database, just the C# script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making this calculations of geting max and adding one to it and then saving back to dB just for primary key saving it back with one valu increased then you should chose AUTO-INCREMENT LIKE. It's syntax is like below:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

It will automatically save value to that field with increment of one and save when new record is getting saved you are not required to pass that auto increment fild in query while saving to dB.

Comment: I can not voteup because I dont have enough rep. I'm beginner and I didn't know about AUTO INCREMENT. Thank you for letting me know. Everything works fine. :)

Comment: @DannyHai you can still use the check mark (under the down arrow) to mark an answer as "correct", that will help both your and Jenish's reputation ;)